# Is it possible to autowire local server port outside of a test class in Spring Boot test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, unit-testing, spring-boot-test

I was wishing to wrap my controller calls for rest api testing for handy usage and wrote

```
class BaseControllerWrapper {
    @LocalServerPort
    int port;
    ...
}

@Component
class SpecificControllerWrapper extends BaseControllerWrapper {
    void callEndpoint() {
        ...
    }
}

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class PermissionsTest {


     @Autowire
     SpecificControllerWrapper specificControllerWrapper;

     @Test
     public void testSomething() {
         ...
         wrapper.callEndpoint();
         ...
     }

}
```

Unfortunately, Spring was unable to instantiate beans with

> Error creating bean with name 'specificControllerWrapper': Injection of autowired
> dependencies failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
> 'local.server.port' in value "${local.server.port}"   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:405)

Is it possible to overcome?

Comment: The fact that `@LocalServerPort` is in the `org.springframework.boot.test.web.server` package (in newer versions) should give an indication. The answer is no. I also fail to see what you gain over using a `TestRestTemplate` injected by Spring as that will have the proper base url set already.

Comment: @M.Deinum what do you mean rest template contains url set? Examples show that urls are built programmatically upon use, for example here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testresttemplate  How to reach base url if it is inside template?

Comment: You only need the `/whatever/your/endpoint/is` part you don't need the `http://localhost:<port>/<context>` part.

Comment: Can you provide any examples? You mean I should pass only tail as url for https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/web/client/TestRestTemplate.html#getForEntity-java.net.URI-java.lang.Class- ? How would it know context then?

Comment: Spring Boot takes care of setting the base url (as I stated before). It does this by using a dedicated `UriTemplateHandler` for the `TestRestTempate`. It will automatically add `http[s]://localhost:<port>/<context-path>`. You don't need to do anything for that.

Comment: @M.Deinum how to get for object? It requires URL.

Comment: No it doesn't it requires a path not a full URL, the name of the variable is confusing.